# Buffers and Memoryview Objects explained for the non-C programmer

Tags: python, c, python-2.7, python-2.x, memoryview

Python 2.7 has introduced a [new API for buffers and memoryview objects](http://docs.python.org/c-api/buffer.html).

I read the documentation on them and I think I got the basic concept (accessing the internal data of an object in a raw form without copying it, which I suppose means a "faster and less memory-hungry" way to get object data), but to really understand the documentation, the reader should have a knowledge of C that is beyond the one I have.

I would be very grateful if somebody would take the time to:

- explain buffers and memoryview objects in "layman terms" and
- describe a scenario in which using buffers and memoryview objects would be "the Pythonic way" of doing things

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422685/what-is-python-buffer-type-for/3422740#3422740), which explains their use in pure Python, though it doesn't go into the C API.

Comment: @Scott - Already read (and upvoted) before I posted this question. :) Very useful indeed. @agf's answer (and link!) helped me understand more... Still the C-API thing confuses me a bit: is that only mentioned to explain the rationale for the creation of the `memoryview` type, or is there something I should absolutely know about it? And also: why is it not possible to write objects exposing the buffer interface? It's a design choice from Guido & Co. or it's an implicit limitation of python internal working?

Comment: @agf - Thank you for the comment, but I think my comment was misunderstood: I was referring to @Scott's own answer that he linked in his comment. The last sentence of the answer is: "Note also that you can't implement a buffer interface for your own objects without delving into the C API, i.e. you can't do it in pure Python."

Comment: @mac Yeah, I missed that. I think the C-API is mentioned so often because until Python 2.6, it was the only way to use the (old) buffer interface / protocol. So people already familiar with "buffers" in Python think of them in that light. You don't need to know anything about it to use the 2.6+ buffer object or the 2.7+ memoryview object. It does, however, explain why buffer objects are read only: because buffers have always been read only from code written in Python, so we need to call a read-write buffer available to Python code something else (a memoryview).

Comment: My understanding is that there's no fundamental reason why pure Python types couldn't implement a memoryview interface, it just hasn't been provided. I guess that if you really need it then you're probably doing something fairly low-level and performance critical and are already using C (or perhaps should be using it). That's not my experience, but either way I don't think we'll get pure Python memoryview types any time soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a line from a hash function I wrote:

```
M = tuple(buffer(M, i, Nb) for i in range(0, len(M), Nb))
```

This will split a long string, M, into shorter 'strings' of length Nb, where Nb is the number of bytes / characters I can handle at a time. It does this WITHOUT copying any parts of the string, as would happen if I made slices of the string like so:

```
M = tuple(M[i*Nb:i*Nb+Nb] for i in range(0, len(M), Nb))
```

I can now iterate over M just as I would had I sliced it:

```
H = key
for Mi in M:
    H = encrypt(H, Mi)
```

Basically, buffers and memoryviews are efficient ways to deal with the immutability of strings in Python, and the general copying behavior of slicing etc. A memoryview is just like a buffer, except you can also write to it, not just read.

While the main buffer / memoryview doc is about the C implementation, the standard types page has a bit of info under memoryview: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview-type

Edit: Found this in my bookmarks, http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Ago7BXl1_qUJ:mattgattis.com/2010/3/9/python-memory-views+site:mattgattis.com+python&hl=en&client=firefox-a&gl=us&strip=1 is a REALLY good brief writeup.

Edit 2: Turns out I got that link from [When should a memoryview be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845418/when-should-a-memoryview-be-used) in the first place, that question was never answered in detail and the link was dead, so hopefully this helps.

Comment: Wait... can you actually *mutate strings* (and/or other immutable objects) using a `memoryview`?

Comment: No - you can only mutate mutable objects, like a bytearray. memoryview has a `readonly` attribute, which will tell you if you can.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the answer I was looking for is that `buffer` is the "old way", that `memoryview` is the new way, but was backported to 2.7 -  see the archived blog [here](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20140706162028/http://demianbrecht.github.io/posts/2013/02/10/buffer-and-memoryview/)

This doesn't answer my question of why the C API I thought I implemented in 2.7 lets me construct a `buffer` but not a `memoryview`...

To get `memoryview` to work in Python 2.7, you need to have the `Py_TPFLAGS_HAVE_NEWBUFFER` flag set in `tp_flags`. I found that the built-in `bytearray` source was a good reference; it is in `Include/bytearrayobject.h` and `Objects/bytearrayobject.c`.

Comment: The link in this answer is dead.

Comment: I resurrected the link buhahah