# What is the advantage of memoryview compared with "=" in memory sharing in python?

Tags: python

I have two examples:

```
# example one:
>>> import array
>>> arr = array.array("h", [-2,-1,0,1,2])
>>> print(list(arr))                       # [-2,-1,0,1,2]

>>> mem_arr = memoryview(arr)
>>> mem_arr.tolist()                       # returns [-2,-1,0,1,2]

>>> mem_arr[0] = 1
>>> mem_arr.tolist()                       # returns [1,-1,0,1,2]

>>> print(list(arr))                       # [1,-1,0,1,2]
```

And

```
# example two:
>>> import array
>>> arr = array.array("h", [-2,-1,0,1,2])
>>> b = arr
>>> print(list(b))                        # [-2,-1,0,1,2]

>>> b[0] = 1
>>> print(list(b))                        # [1,-1,0,1,2]

>>> print(list(arr))                      # [1,-1,0,1,2]
```

Both two examples modify the value in the array without copying the original one. The only difference I think is that:

In first example, I created `memoryview` object which use different memory block from the original array. In the second example, two references `arr` and `b` both point to the original array.

**So, what is the advantage of `memoryview` compared with "=" in memory sharing, or under what circumstances should I use `memoryview`?**

Comment: "`memoryview` object which use different memory block from the original array" seems like a misunderstanding. A memoryview is a view to the same buffer, though the memoryview object itself is of course not the array object. One of the things memory views are useful for is taking slices of the buffer that do not copy, but create new views, compared to slicing the array.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18655648/what-exactly-is-the-point-of-memoryview-in-python

Comment: @Ilja Everilä, Thanks!

Comment: @Ilja Everilä, I forget the buffer. `memoryview` is exactly more efficient when doing with many binary things.