# How to count the length between two characters in a string

Tags: javascript, python

Hey I'm trying to create a function that takes in a string and a letter as arguments, identifies if there are two of this letter within the string, and then returns the number of characters between the two plus the letters.
So 'Saturday' and 'a' would return 6.

```
def sublength(string, char):
    new_string = ''
    for i in string:
        if i == char:
            new_string.append(i)
            if i != char:
                new_string.append(i)
                if i == char:
                    new_string.append(i)
                    break
    return len(new_string)
```

What I want to do is iterate through string until char is found, add this character to new_string, continue to iterate and add the subsequent characters until char is found again, add it and then stop. This would be done in one iteration. However, as it's currently constructed, my function iterates through all of the string looking for matches and then stops.
How do I either do this in one iteration or break up the string to achieve the same functionality?
Thanks!

**If you can provide a solution in JS as well I would really appreciate it!!**

Comment: do you want the first repeated letter or the largest repeated gap?

Comment: You can keep indexes of first and second occurrence of char 'c'. Currently, when you are appending then you are recreating string. By design string are immutable. So, its better to slice them once by having indexes.

Comment: I want the character count between and including the two common characters. So in my example of 'Saturday' and 'a' the answer would be 6: a-1, t-2, u-3, r-4, d-5, a-6. I want to do this without RegEx.

Comment: Alternatively, you can play with regex to achieve the same.

Comment: What should 'banana' and sep 'a' return?

Comment: I'm only interested in strings that contain char twice so 'banana' and 'a' should return 0

Comment: Should 'banana' and 'c' also return 0?  What about 'banana' and 'b'?

Comment: Any string that doesn't have char * 2 should return 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Little known fact, `str.index` accepts a second argument for where to begin searching from:

```py
>>> s = "Saturday"
>>> first = s.index("a")
>>> second = s.index("a", first + 1)
>>> second - first + 1
6
```

This is more efficient than `string[start+1:].index(char)` because that way [makes an unnecessary copy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64871976/674039).

Putting it into a function:

```py
def sublength(string, char):
    if string.count(char) != 2:
        return 0
    first = string.index(char)
    second = string.index(char, first + 1)
    return second - first + 1
```

Returns `0` if `char` is not present exactly twice within `string`.

Comment: Yeah. To add it accepts third argument as end index till where to search.

Comment: Also, wrap this under a try catch to avoid edge case errors.

Comment: Hmm...I actually might agree with your second point.  In fact, I like it better than the extra walk over the string to check for two characters.  But it's fine.  As to the first point, it's a matter of quality of the answer.  It's hard for someone to copy/paste your answer to try it or to use it, for instance. - Your second version is good. Got my up vote.

Comment: @Steve  Unfortunately the check for exactly 2 characters is necessary, OP said *I'm only interested in strings that contain char twice so 'banana' and 'a' should return 0*.

Comment: Ah!  I didn't see the late comments.  Cool.

Answer (score 0):

Shortcut method:

```
try:
    print(string[string.index(char)+1:].index(char)+2)
except:
    print(char ,'is not present twice in ', string)
```

OR

```
pos = string[string.find(char)+1:].find(char)+2
if pos == 1 :
    print(char ,'is not present twice in ', string)
else:
    print("Are present at a distance of",pos)
```

Comment: Cool! But it fails if there'snot the target char in the string. Anyway it's easy to modify this shortcut to handle it! +1

Comment: This returns 2. How could it be changed to return 6 as intended? Thanks!

Comment: Yeah.  Needs to handle failure cases (no match, one match, bad input)

Comment: Output for failure cases added.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this by using regex. But to follow your try, see whats wrong when you see a solution next to your try.

```
def sublength(string, char):
new_string = ''
found = False
for i in string:
    if i == char:
        if not found:
            new_string += i
            found = True
        else:
            new_string += i
            found = False
            break
    elif found:
        new_string += i
if found:
    new_string = ""
return len(new_string)
```

But keep in mind, there is no check for upper and lower case ...

Update: Here the solution with Regex

```
import re
if re.search("a.*?a", "Saturday"):
    print(len(re.search("a.*?a", "Saturday").group(0)))
else:
    print("Nope")
```

Comment: Your second solution is kinda cool, although it's too bad you have to do the matching twice.  If you stored away the match first, and then used it twice, you could avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity, an approach using `regex`:

```
import re

def substring_length(string, char):
    match = re.search(f'{char}.+{char}', string)
    match_length = len(match.group(0)) if match else 0
    return match_length
```

Some tests:

```
# Returns the expected results when there are two target characters
print(substring_length('Saturday', 'a'))
6

# Returns 0 when there aren't at least two target characters
print(substring_length('Saturday', 'z'))
0

# When there are more than two target characters, calculate the length from the start matching character to the last matching character
print(substring_length('Researcher', 'e'))
8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def f(s, c):
    s = s.lower()
    if s.count(c) != 2:
        return 0
    return s.index(c, mn+1)-s.index(c)+1
    

f('Saturday', 'a')
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, you could do it this way:

```
function subLength(word, character) {
  const regexString = `[${character}]`;
  const regex = new RegExp(regexString, 'g');
  const found = word.match(regex);
  
  if (found.length !== 2) {
    return 0;
  } 
  
  first = word.indexOf(character);
  second = word.lastIndexOf(character);
  
  return second - first + 1;
};

subLength('Saturday', 'a'); // returns 6
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use string.index() method to ease your situation:

```
def sublength(string, char):
    try:
        start = string.index(char)
        end = string.index(char, start+1)
    except: return 'No two instances'
    else: return end +2
```

index() will return the position of character in the string. You can use it to find indices and number of characters between them.

### How does this works?

1. start finds first occurrence of character
2. end finds first occurance of character AFTER the index at which
   start is discovered (thats why indexing from `start+1` so to search
   string from after the first occurance till end. Because thats
   where we need to search for second occurenece)
3. if both indices are found, it goes on to `else` to return difference
   Plus 2 as it is counting both elements (mere difference return number of characters between them excluding both)
4. if both arent found it returns string : `'No two instances'`

P.S. returns 6 for `sublength('Saturday', 'a')` i.e. works as intended and is one-go!

Comment: This is great! can you explain the end variable and return statement? Thanks!

Comment: `index` takes a starting position.  No need to slice the target string

Comment: Its fixed now! No need to add start again as it is incorporating that in end logic

Comment: That `index` takes a starting position is exactly why it isn't necessary to slice the string.  Just have it start looking at 1 past the first match the second time.  (see @wim's answer...no slice...no problem)

Answer (score -1):

Little long solution:-

```
public static int getCharBetween(String s, char c){
        if(s.equals(null) ||s.length()==0){
            return -1;
        }
        char[] ch=s.toCharArray();
        List<Integer> list= new ArrayList<>();
        for(char cha:ch){
            if(cha==c){
                list.add(s.indexOf(cha));
                s=s.substring(s.indexOf(cha)+1, s.length()-1);
                if(list.size()==2){
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if(list.size()==0){
            return -1;
        }
        return (list.get(1)-list.get(0))-1;
}
```