# Matching the start of a substring in Python RegEx

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match parentheses unless they're escaped in Python. The test case I'm using is this:

```
s  = "aa}}bb"
co = re.compile(r"(^|[^e])(})")
print(s[0:], co.search(s))
print(s[1:], co.search(s, 1))
print(s[2:], co.search(s, 2))
print(s[3:], co.search(s, 3))  # This outputs None?!
```

The intent of the RegEx pattern is "either there is no character in front of the curly brace, or there is a character that isn't the escape (here `e`)". The last substring I'm searching was `s[3:] == }bb`, I thought. It doesn't match the pattern however, and although this is quite strange, I guess this is because

1. the RegEx-created substring *does* know that there is no start-of-line before it, and
2. it *doesn't* know that there was any character in front of it.

In other words: `s[3:]` is not actually what's being searched. One way I see to circumvent this is to just `co.search(s[3:])`, which will give me the start-of-line. I'd like to just use `search`'s argument instead of slicing, because I'm working with big strings [and slicing copies memory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64871976/9352077). Can it be done?

Comment: Per the manual, "_pos_ ... is not completely equivalent to slicing the string; the `^` pattern character matches at the real beginning of the string ... but not necessarily at the index where the search is to start." https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.search

Comment: What you probably want is "negative look-behind"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Yes, that's documented behaviour:

  > *pos* ... is not completely equivalent to slicing the string; the `^` pattern character matches at the real beginning of the string ... but not necessarily at the index where the search is to start.

  https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.search
- What you probably want here is "negative lookbehind" which is written `(?<!...)`; so with an escape of `e` that'd be `(?<!e)`

  ```
  s  = "aa}}bb"
  co = re.compile(r"(?<!e)(})")
  print(s[0:], co.search(s))
  print(s[1:], co.search(s, 1))
  print(s[2:], co.search(s, 2))
  print(s[3:], co.search(s, 3))
  ```